# Creating CSV spreadsheets from web tables acquired through BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, csv, parsing, beautifulsoup, datatable

I am trying to parse the second table from this website (https://blog.prepscholar.com/act-to-sat-conversion) and output it as a CSV file. I couldn't write the output into CSV so I tried to create strings for each row and then make a list of it to write to CSV but I failed. Could you help me? Thank you so much!

This is my code so far:

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
tpage1 = 'https://blog.prepscholar.com/act-to-sat-conversion'
hpage = urlopen(tpage1)
bs = BeautifulSoup(hpage, 'html.parser')

for h1 in bs.find_all('h1'):
    print(h1.get_text())
table = bs.find_all('table')[1]
rows = table.find_all('tr')
headers = table.find_all('th')
rownum = 0

for row in rows:
    rownum += 1
    cellnum = 0

    new_row = ''
    for cell in row.find_all(['td','th']):
        cellnum += 1

        print(rownum, cellnum, cell.get_text())
```

This code gives me an output (a snippet is below)

```
SAT / ACT Prep Online Guides and Tips
1 1 ACT Composite Score
1 2 Estimated SAT Composite
1 3 Estimated SAT Composite Range
2 1 36
2 2 2390
2 3 2320-2400
3 1 35
3 2 2260
3 3 2320-2310
4 1 34
4 2 2170
4 3 2140-2220
```

How could I modify this to be able to output into a CSV?

Comment: `csw_writer.writerow([rownum, cellnum, cell.get_text()])` ?

Comment: what means "failed"? If you get error message then you should show it in question (not in comment) as text (not image). Don't expect that we will run code to see error message - and code can run correctly on our computers.

Comment: try `pandas` - `all_tables = pandas.read_html('https://blog.prepscholar.com/act-to-sat-conversion')` and `all_tables[0].to_csv("output1.csv")` and `all_tables[1].to_csv("output2.csv")`

Comment: maybe you should keep cells from one row in single list, not in string and later write this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

all_tables = pd.read_html('https://blog.prepscholar.com/act-to-sat-conversion')
all_tables[0].to_csv("output1.csv")
all_tables[1].to_csv("output2.csv")
```

With BeautifulSoup it would need more work.

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://blog.prepscholar.com/act-to-sat-conversion'

html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find_all('table')[1]

fh = open('output.csv', 'w')
cvs_writer = csv.writer(fh)

all_data = []
rows = table.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cells = row.find_all(['td','th'])
    row_data = []
    for cell in cells:
        row_data.append(cell.get_text())
    all_data.append(row_data)
    cvs_writer.writerow(row_data)

print(all_data)
fh.close()
```

Little shorter with list comprehension and without keeping data in `all_data`

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://blog.prepscholar.com/act-to-sat-conversion'

html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find_all('table')[1]

fh = open('output.csv', 'w')
cvs_writer = csv.writer(fh)

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    row_data = [cell.get_text() for cell in row.find_all(['td','th'])]
    cvs_writer.writerow(row_data)

fh.close()
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much furas! I hadn't even considered using pandas!